# Add to basket with arrays prints mysqli erros

Tags: php, arrays, session, mysqli

I'm working on a add to basket script, for a school project, but it cause me some errors.

I have an add.php and index.php file, who works together.

add.php looks like:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    if (empty($_SESSION['kurv'])) {
       $_SESSION['kurv'] = array();
    }

    array_push($_SESSION['kurv'], $_GET['id']);
    header("location: index.php");
?>
```

My script in index.php that shows the elements put in array looks like:

```
<?php

  $_SESSION['kurv'] = array();

  $DBConnect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
  $arrayID = implode(',', $_SESSION['kurv']);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM produkter WHERE id IN ($arrayID)";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row2['titel'];?></td>
            <td class="h"><?php echo $row2['pris'] . " kr.";?> <button    class="knap"><a>-</a></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <?php

        }
   ?>
```

But for some reason i can't explain and have tried to fix, this causes me these errors:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 624
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 626

Can someone please try to explain this to me, since i'm still a bit new in to PHP?

Comment: always code with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on top of your PHP scripts.

Comment: why are you adding brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection variable is

```
$DBConnect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
```

SO use `DBConnect`

```
$result = $DBConnect->query($sql);
```

Instead `$conn`

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Use **[num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)** to check weather your query return result or not

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produkter WHERE id IN ($arrayID)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row2['titel']; ?></td>
                <td class="h"><?php echo $row2['pris'] . " kr."; ?> <button    class="knap"><a>-</a></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    echo "NO result foumd";
}
```

To check error in query and connection use

```
/* check connection */
if ($DBConnect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $DBConnect->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if (!$DBConnect->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $DBConnect->error);
}
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hi, thank you. This solved one of the errors. I still got an:

Comment: **Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 626** though. I have allready a code that checks if the query returns results, just not included it!

Comment: echo `$sql = "SELECT * FROM produkter WHERE id IN ($arrayID)";
` and paste what it echo

Comment: SELECT * FROM produkter WHERE id IN ()

Comment: It means `$arrayID` is empty!!

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

This is the code on the line that erros in my index.php

Comment: `print_r($_SESSION)` value and remove `$_SESSION['kurv'] = array();` fron top

Comment: Yeah i figured. But it seems that it registers when i add something to the array because the "Basket is empty" text, goes away when i press "Add to basket" and put it in a session.